# Create a column that reports the values of the previous survey

Tags: powerbi, dax, calculated-columns

i have a dataset like this:

| KPI | Date | Value | Value Prev Survey |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01/01/2023 | 100 |  |
| 1 | 01/02/2023 | 120 | 100 |
| 1 | 01/03/2023 | 130 | 120 |
| 2 | 01/01/2023 | 75 |  |
| 2 | 01/03/2023 | 34 | 75 |
| 2 | 01/06/2023 | 31 | 34 |

I tried this formula:

```
Value Prev Survey = CALCULATE(
    SUM(test_table[Value]), 
    DATESMTD(DATEADD(raw_table_fatturazione[Date],-1,MONTH))
  )
```

But it doesn't work, as it gives me all the empty fields in the table and, furthermore, I should tell it to take the previous reading for each KPI and not the month.

I should calculate the column (not measurement) "Value at previous measurement", which tells me for each kpi, the value of the previous measurement.

Thanks a lot

Comment: You have the problem, now you need to report back with what code you have tried, and any error messages or wrong values you got instead.

Comment: Ok thanks, I changed the text.. I hope I was clear

Comment: That should help someone find your question to assist you.  If you can you might even click the CODE button and put the code inside that and other formatting on your question to make it even easier to read, as easier to read and copy and paste questions get answered more quickyly on average.

Comment: Ok perfect, thanks :)

Comment: Np, and btw nice work, looks good, and seems to have gotten results!  Welcome to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Value Prev Survey = 
  var thisKpiRows = ALLEXCEPT('test_table', 'test_table'[KPI])
  var thisRowDate = [Date]
  var prevDate = CALCULATE(
    MAX('test_table'[Date]),
    thisKpiRows,
    'test_table'[Date] < thisRowsDate
  )

  return CALCULATE(
    MAX('test_table'[Score]),
    thisKpiRows,
    'test_table'[Date] = prevAvailableDate
  )
```